# pdf via latex cannot render symbols of pi with graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pdflatex

I want to ask a question about downloading a notebook in Jupyter that uses matplotlib and xticks.

I produced the following code block as part of a function that plots sine and cosine:

```
X = linspace(-pi, pi, 128)
C = cos(X)
S = sin(X)

figure(figsize=(10,6))

xlim(-pi*1.1, pi*1.1)
ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

xticks([-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi],
      ['$-\pi$', '$-\pi/2$','$0$', '$+\pi/2', '$+\pi$'])
yticks([-1, 0, 1],
       ['$-1$', '$0$', '$+1$'])
plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth = 2.5, linestyle = "-", label="cosine")
plot(X, S, color="red", linestyle = "None", marker = "o", label = "sine")

legend(loc="upper left")
show()
```

Now, this gives me the following graph:

[image: Graph produced upon execution of code block]

This is satisfactory.
However, when I try to download the PDF of the notebook with Latex formatting, I receive the following error:

```
[1-22]
[23]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2208--2209

[24]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 2252--2253

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.2265 dollar signs: `\$\pi
                           \$'. For consistency we'll use math rendering for
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.2265 dollar signs: `\$\pi
                           \$'. For consistency we'll use math rendering for
Output written on notebook.pdf (24 pages).
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Errors [1-22] were of the same nature, so I omitted them for clarity.

It appears that the Latex package cannot render the $\pi$ symbol before download, and I don't understand why?

How can I fix this matter?

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one closing `$` missing: `'$+\pi/2',`